# Is there an argument for chromedriver to accept notifications?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, nightwatchjs

I am using Nightwatch to run my chromedriver, and I need to accept notifications through the browser.  I have found this [list](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) of chromedriver arguments, but I haven't been able to find any that automatically accept notifications.

Is there an argument that I can use to do this?

Comment: does this help? https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/3#issuecomment-157442454

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The notifications pop up is from the browser and is not an alert. I will update with a screenshot shortly.  Thank you though!

Comment: `--disable-notifications` from https://www.maketecheasier.com/useful-chrome-command-line-switches/

Comment: I’m needing to enable the notifications if possible, not disable.

Comment: oh, sorry, misread :)

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a better solution so far, but I'm using `--accept-notifications` and it's working well enough.